# seaborn violinplot ValueError: Could not interpret input 'amplitude'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, seaborn, violin-plot

I want to make a violinplot with this data [My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO6em.jpg), but I always get an error message like "Could not interpret input 'amplitude'".
do you have any solution I'm stuck for 3 days :(

Comment: Could you add the code that reproduces the error? Without seeing the code, it's blind guessing how you are calling `violinplot`. Preferably, you also add your test data as text, not as image.  Is your call similar to `sns.violinplot(data=df, x='amplitude', ....)`? Did you look at the examples in the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html) and tried similar constructions?

Comment: There is a whitespace at the end of the column name in your dataframe.